# Update Cell Content Based on Existing Reference Cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following situation:

[image: Current Data Structure]

I would like have EACH initial *Ref. Cell* cell and its associated blank cells, for example A2:A7, updated so that its results in the following data structure:

[image: Desired Data Structure]

I have tried using formulas containing a combination of COUNT, COUNTBLANK, ROW() but have failed miserably in achieving the desired outcome.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with vba, maybe something like this ?

```
Sub Macro1()
For Each cell In Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If cell.End(xlDown).Row = Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
Set oEnd = cell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)
Set rngNum = cell
num = "'" & cell.Value & ":"
n = Range(cell, oEnd).Rows.Count
For i = 1 To n
rngNum.Value = num & i
Set rngNum = rngNum.Offset(1, 0)
Next i
Next cell
End Sub
```

But the weakness, the code will stop at the last row value in column A.
For example based on your first image, the code will stop at 3:1 while you are expecting this 3:1 row will change to 3:1:1 and the next row value is 3:1:2

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked successfully on a +130K row file. Much appreciated. The GIF was a particularly nice touch :)

Comment: Glad I can help, Ghulam.

Answer (score 2):

In `A2`, formula copied down :

```
="1:"&COUNTA(B$2:B2)&":"&ROW(A1)-MATCH("zz",B$2:B2)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @bosco_yip - that worked great. But I realised I did not fully detailed my scenario. After a few rows the "Ref Cell" changes so that the leading digit(s) are no longer '1'.
I updated the original question with the correct details. Hopefully you can provide a solution to this updated scenario.

Comment: You can't remove your original tables and revised a new one. You can edit your post in adding more details to clarify your question but the original tables must be remained. Sorry I can't give you further help.

Comment: I was unaware of the prohibition on altering the text of an original question. I was sincerely trying to clear up the ambiguity/confusion of my original question. I did not mean to cause any offence.